# How can I change font color after its has created

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, scene2d

I am using java, libgdx, scence2d.

I have set bitMapFont in constructor. Now How can I change font color after its has created? I want to change in render method.

This my constructor where I am creating BitmapFont for title and menuItems(3 buttons)

```
public menuScreen() {
    sb = new SpriteBatch();

    stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),
            true);
    bitMapFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/font.fnt"), false);
    labelStyle = new LabelStyle(bitMapFont, Color.WHITE);
    label = new Label("Asteroids", labelStyle);
    float width = bitMapFont.getBounds(title).width;
    label.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - width) / 2,
            (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()) - 100);
    stage.addActor(label);


    //menu items
    menuItems = new String[] { "Play", "HighScores", "Quit" };
    label2 = new Label(menuItems[0], labelStyle);
    label2.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - width) / 2,
            (180 - 35 * 0));

    label3 = new Label(menuItems[1], labelStyle);
    label3.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - width) / 2,
            (180 - 35 * 1));

    label4 = new Label(menuItems[2], labelStyle);
    label4.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - width) / 2,
            (180 - 35 * 2));

    stage.addActor(label2);
    stage.addActor(label3);
    stage.addActor(label4);
}
```

draw title and menus items

```
public void draw() {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(MyGdxGame.camera.combined);
    sb.begin();


   //if user press 'Play' menu item
   if(currentItem == 1){
       //How to change label2 color??????
   }

    // update and draw stage
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();

    sb.end();
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention which language this is.. also tag the question with that language

Answer (score 0):

If you never plan to change the color of any one label, then just give it a different LabelStyle to begin with, specifying the desired color in the LabelStyle.

If you want to change a label's color at will, use `label.getBitmapFontCache().setColor()` before you set the new text of the label.